# Как сделать ответ понятным для ВК?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Мне нужно сделать ответ читабельным для пользователей ВК. У меня есть бот которому пишешь некий ключ , по-которому идет запрос для парса. Но ответ получается не читабельный для пользователей.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
import requests
import sys

groups = {
    'т-691': 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id=26',
    'т-717': 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id=62',
    'т-716': 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id=30',
    'т-692': 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id=40'
}

group = sys.argv[1]
url = 'https://kbp.by/rasp/timetable/view_beta_tbp/?cat=group&id={}'.format(groups[group])

r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
pairs_list = soup.select('div.pair')

def parse_pair(pair):
    extra = pair.select_one('.extra').text
    subject = pair.select_one('.subject').text
    teachers = [t.text.strip() for t in pair.select('.teacher') if t.text]
    group = pair.select_one('.group').text
    place = pair.select_one('.place').text

    return {
        'extra': extra,
        'subject': subject,
        'teachers': teachers,
        'group': group,
        'place': place
    }

table_rows = soup.select_one('table').select('tr')
pairs_list = [row.select('div.pair') for row in table_rows if row.select('div.pair')]
schedule_data = [[parse_pair(pair) for pair in week] for week in pairs_list]

j = 0
shedule = []
while j < len(schedule_data):
    i = 0
    shedule.append([])
    while i < len(schedule_data[i]):
        shedule[j].append(schedule_data[i][j])
        i += 1
    j += 1

print(shedule)
```

Вот как на сайте [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот ответ от ВКбота[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте библиотеку `json` для парсинга и представьте в нужном Вам виде.

Comment: nomnoms12 , не знаю как это сделать и представить.

Comment: Даже не знаю, что Вам посоветовать. Объём информации слишком большой. Может стоит отправлять в ВК картинкой? Но это довольно заморочно...

Answer (score 0):

После парсинга вы получаете список внутри которого список внутри которого словари, если не знаете как пользоваться JSON, самый простой метод, перед отправкой написать цикл, который будет доставать необходимые данные и добавлять их в строку